# Passing function return into a text string within PySimpleGUI window

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Sorry for the noob question.
I've defined a button in PySimpleGUI that should check the number of records in the API and return in a text field in the window, that number, within a text string.

I'm doing something wrong with the hierarchy of statements, I think.
When I add indentation to the last two lines quoted, then nothing happens upon button click, but if I reduce indents, an error says that 'response' is undefined.
Passing the function result into the string directly doesn't seem to work either (error says you can't do it).
I think I've tried every combination of indents and also parameters given to the get_entries function.

```
if event == '-CHECK-':
    baseurl_short = 'https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements?page=1&limit=25&format=json&api-version=1.2&sort=provider-code:ASC'
    if method == ['Service Type']:
        api_url_short = ''.join([baseurl_short, '&serviceType=', type_input, '&year=', year_input, '&branch=', region_input])
    else:
        api_url_short = ''.join([baseurl_short, '&productCode=', code_input, '&year=', year_input, '&branch=', region_input])
    def main_request_short(api_url):
        r = requests.get(api_url)
        return r.json()
    def get_entries(response):
        return math.ceil(response['meta']['count'])
    sum_entries = get_entries(response)
    window['-OUTPUT-'].update('Downloading ' + sum_entries + ' records')
```

Comment: Well, where were you expecting the value of `response` to come from?  There's no definition of that name anywhere in the fragment of code you've showed us.

Comment: Thank you for that! That question was major help, actually... Works now.